# Storing permanent variable in php

Tags: php, variables

How can I store value in php for later use? for example I want to make install script for CMS system, in installation file I want user to type his db_name... and i want to use this name in all of connection scripts. Should I use SESSION or something like that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose, you can use built in method [tmpfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) which creates a temporary file with read/write mode

Answer (score 0):

as you want that file for connecting database every time, you should go for creating a php file with the permission of read and write obviously.

Answer (score 0):

- Make a page
- List variables
- `include 'page';` in all other pages to access variable

Answer (score 0):

I think that a SESSION is a good place to do it since PHP sessions is stored on the server.